# Making Answers Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript

I am asking the user a question and I want their answer to be case insensitive. They should have a correct answer whether they use the capital letters or not. Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
var name = prompt('Enter your name');
var correctAnswers = 0;
var questions = 15;

document.write('Okay '+name+' here is Question 1: What does html stand for?:  HyperText Markup Language, High Track Making Language, High Tech Making Language');
var answer = prompt('Okay '+name+' here is Question 1: What does html stand for?:  HyperText Markup Language, High Track Making Language, High Tech Making Language');

if (answer === 'HyperText Markup Language') {
    console.log(correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1);
    console.log('That is correct!');
    document.write('<div>That is correct!</div>');
} else {
    console.log('Sorry that is wrong. The correct answer is HyperText Markup Language.');
    document.write('<div>Sorry that is wrong. The correct answer is HyperText Markup Language.</div>');
}
```

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()` to convert the string to lower case and compare with all lowercase answer. `answer.toLowerCase() === 'hypertext markup language'`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the answer to lower case or upper case using `toLowerCase();` or `toUpperCase();`

```
if (answer.toLowerCase() === ('HyperText Markup Language').toLowerCase()) {
    console.log(correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1);
    console.log('That is correct!');
    document.write('<div>That is correct!</div>');
} else {
    console.log('Sorry that is wrong. The correct answer is HyperText Markup Language.');
    document.write('<div>Sorry that is wrong. The correct answer is HyperText Markup Language.</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to all lowercase, use:

```
if (answer.toLowerCase() === "string") { 
    // code here
}
```